# Corda DLT for IoT

Tags: iot, blockchain, corda

I'm interested in create a smart home environment using the concept of Blockchain, so I was introduced to Corda and I would like to know if it is possible to set every IoT device as a node at the Corda network. 
If not, is there a framework or another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 3, Corda wouldn't be a good fit for IoT devices at this stage. The first problem you'd encounter is that there's no equivalent of a "light client". Each node needs to run a resource-intensive Java process with a 200mb+ heap size.

As a first step in addressing this, Corda has published design docs for Project Maximus, which would allow different users to "time-share" a single node. This would mean that each user would only have to run a client, instead of a full node. You can find the Maximus design doc here: https://groups.io/g/corda-dev/topic/27242114#469.